# Expanding date range to have row per instance, taking dose frequency into account

Tags: r, dataframe, date, data-manipulation, units-of-measurement

Hi I have a dataset that I need the dates to be expanded to have a row per date entry. The problem is more complex due to the schedule variable. There are 19 scheduling options (see attached image).

For any "nx a day" options I just need the dose to be multiplied by the number of times administered per day.

The other scheduling options of every other week, day, etc need to be incorporated into the date range (start-stop) expansion.

[image]

Dataset structure

```
structure(list(id = c(1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 
1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010004, 
1010004, 1010016, 1010021, 1010021, 1010026, 1010032, 1010032, 
1010032, 1010032, 1010055, 1010068, 1010107, 1020094, 2010116, 
2010116, 2010125, 2010125, 3010026, 4010026, 4020144), drug = c("Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Calcium Carbonate", "Cefalexin", "Cotrimoxazole", 
"Dexamethasone", "Dextrose 5%/Sodium Chloride 0.9%/Potassium Chloride 20mmol/L", 
"Lactulose", "Morphine", "Morphine", "Oxycodone Immediate Release", 
"Calcitriol", "Vitamin D3", "Heparin Lock", "CMV Immune Globulin 5%", 
"Heparin Lock", "Cysteamine", "CMV Immune Globulin 5%", "Hydromorphone", 
"Leucovorin", "Lorazepam", "Morphine", "Hydromorphone", "Salbutamol", 
"Lorazepam", "Warfarin", "Warfarin", "Heparin", "Lorazepam", 
"Salbutamol", "Sirolimus", "Hydromorphone"), start = structure(c(1247875200, 
1248048000, 1247702400, 1248652800, 1250121600, 1247875200, 1247788800, 
1248220800, 1247961600, 1247961600, 1248134400, 1235001600, 1235001600, 
1280102400, 1290988800, 1290211200, 1298332800, 1284854400, 1365811200, 
1363651200, 1363651200, 1317513600, 1291939200, 1409875200, 1263513600, 
1367452800, 1367366400, 1454803200, 1451088000, 1420070400, 1372809600, 
1342051200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    stop = structure(c(1250035200, 1248048000, 1249948800, 1249689600, 
    1250121600, 1248134400, 1247875200, 1248307200, 1248048000, 
    1248048000, 1248998400, 1235001600, 1235001600, 1280188800, 
    1290988800, 1290816000, 1298332800, 1287360000, 1367452800, 
    1364083200, 1364169600, 1317686400, 1292371200, 1409875200, 
    1264809600, 1371945600, 1371772800, 1456099200, 1455840000, 
    1420070400, 1373155200, 1342051200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dose = c(1000, 1000, 200, 1000, 
    160, 8, 150, 10, 4, 15, 5, 0.25, 400, 2250, 2500, 250, 1, 
    2500, 0.25, 12, 2.2, 3, 6, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 2, 130, 1, 1, 0.5, 
    1), units = c("mg", "mg", "mg (ca++)", "mg", "mg (trimethoprim)", 
    "mg", "ml/hr", "ml", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mcg", "IU", "U", 
    "mg", "U", "drop(s)", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", 
    "ml", "mg", "mg", "mg", "U", "mg", "ml", "mg", "mg"), route = c("Oral", 
    "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Intravenous", "Intravenous", 
    "Oral", "Intravenous", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Injection", 
    "Intravenous", "Injection", "Ophthalmic", "Intravenous", 
    "Intravenous", "Intravenous", "Intravenous", "Intravenous", 
    "Oral", "Inhalation", "Intravenous", "Oral", "Oral", "Intravenous", 
    "Intravenous", "Inhalation", "Oral", "Intravenous"), schedule = c("4x a day", 
    "4x a day", "3x a day", "3x a day", "2x a day", "1x a day", 
    "1x a day", "2x a day", "12x a day", "6x a day", "6x a day", 
    "every other day", "every other day", "Every 7 days", "every other week", 
    "Every 7 days", "24x a day", "every other week", "12x a day", 
    "8x a day", "24x a day", "48x a day", "8x a day", "48x a day", 
    "72x a day", "Every 3 days", "Every 3 days", "96x a day", 
    "96x a day", "72x a day", "every 4 days", "144x a day")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Dataset Structure needed (showing first drug entry for id 1010002 expanded and dailydose calculated

```
structure(list(id = c(1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 
1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 
1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 
1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002, 1010002
), drug = c("Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", 
"Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen", "Acetaminophen"), start = structure(c(1247875200, 
1247961600, 1248048000, 1248134400, 1248220800, 1248307200, 1248393600, 
1248480000, 1248566400, 1248652800, 1248739200, 1248825600, 1248912000, 
1248998400, 1249084800, 1249171200, 1249257600, 1249344000, 1249430400, 
1249516800, 1249603200, 1249689600, 1249776000, 1249862400, 1249948800, 
1250035200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dailydose = c(4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 
    4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 
    4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 4000), units = c("mg", 
    "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", 
    "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", 
    "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg", "mg"), route = c("Oral", "Oral", 
    "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", 
    "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", 
    "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral", "Oral"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Nothing to do with "datatable" issues, but units of measurement is teh key topic so added it.

Answer (score 1):

We can create the 'dailydose' column by parsing the numeric part from 'schedule' and multiplying with 'dose', then loop over the rows with `map2` to create a `list` column from 'start', 'stop' columns and `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     transmute(id, drug, start, stop, 
              dailydose = dose * parse_number(schedule), units, route) %>%
     mutate(start = map2(start, stop, seq, by = 'day')) %>% 
     select(-stop) %>% 
     unnest(c(start))
# A tibble: 378 x 6
#        id drug          start               dailydose units route
#     <dbl> <chr>         <dttm>                  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-18 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 2 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-19 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 3 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-20 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 4 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-21 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 5 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-22 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 6 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-23 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 7 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-24 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 8 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-25 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# 9 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-26 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
#10 1010002 Acetaminophen 2009-07-27 00:00:00      4000 mg    Oral 
# … with 368 more rows
```

---

If `readr` is not available, we can extract the values with `str_extract` and convert to `numeric` i.e. change the `parse_number(schedule)` to  `as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(schedule, '[0-9]+'))`

Comment: Upvoted, but I'm getting: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rowr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)`

Comment: Cannot find it at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/index.html so perhaps you installed from github or some other non-standard location? Noper, seraching with google I see" Package ‘rowr’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Archived on 2020-01-28 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders."

Comment: @42- my version is `packageVersion('readr')
[1] ‘1.3.1’` can you try on a fresh session

Comment: deleted obsolete comments.

Comment: Thank you @akrun, this works perfectly for the daily dose generation. I need id that has a schedule of every 7 days or similar to have their dates expanded using this rule also (ie if the start and stop equals a total of 21 days, there should be 3 rows and not 21)